# Why dress in camouflage if you're with shiny C3PO?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, endor

In the Battle of Endor, why would the rebels dress in camouflage when they have a golden C3PO trailing behind them, squawking all the time?

Comment: Because they'll shoot at the shiny golden droid instead of you? :)

Comment: Maybe clarify whether you're looking for canon or legends answers. +1

Comment: A tactical error- a very bad one, but never the less the rebels won

Comment: @Morgan  Perhaps not such a tactical error, given that without C3PO, the assault team leaders would have been barbecued by the Ewoks! :)

Comment: They need R2-D2 to pinpoint the enemy base. They need C-3PO to understand R2-D2

Comment: @Richard yah now that I think about it that totally needed him for translation

Comment: And the storm troopers. My Yoda, why would they insist on wearing all white on Endoor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- ***Why take C-3PO:***

  - The planet has a lifeform that doesn't understand Galactic Standard

    Which was a good call, given that the lifeform tried to spit-fry and eat the team.

    > Luke turned to the golden droid. “Threepio, can you understand what they’re saying?”
    >   (*RotJ novelization*)
  - R2-D2 can't talk to any of them, as Richard's comment stated. And R2 is an important part of the unit, given his sensors and his ability to plug into Imperial networks like on Death Star.

    > Artoo sat, unmoving e**xcept for the little radar screen that stuck out the top of his blue and silver dome, revolving, scanning the forest**. He exuded the calm patience of a utilized function, a program being run.
    >   Suddenly, **he beeped**.
    >   Threepio ceased his obsessive polishing and looked apprehensively into the forest. “**Someone’s coming,” he translated**.

    ...

    > Luke, Chewbacca, General Solo, and the two droids faced in the opposite direction. **Artoo led the way, his revolving scanner sensing for all the parameters that described his mistress**; and the others followed him into the woods.

    ....

    > Luke, Chewie, Han, and Threepio picked their way methodically through the undergrowth **behind Artoo, whose antenna continued to revolve**. It was remarkable the way the little droid was able to blaze a trail over jungle terrain like this, but he did it without fuss, the miniature cutting tools on his walkers and dome slicing neatly through anything too dense to push out of the way.
    >   Artoo suddenly stopped, causing some consternation on the part of his followers. **His radar screen spun faster, he clicked and whirred to himself, then darted forward with an excited announcement. “Vrrr dEEp dWP booooo dWEE op!”**
    >   **Threepio raced behind him. “Artoo says the rocket bikes are right up—oh, dear.”**

    ...

    > Han punched out the stolen code on the control panel keys—but this time, the door didn’t open. It had been reprogrammed as soon as they’d been caught. “The terminal doesn’t work now,” he muttered.
    >   ...
    >   “**We need Artoo**,” she {{Leia}} shouted.
    >   Han nodded, took out his comlink, **pushed the sequence that signaled the little droid** and reached for the weapon Leia couldn’t get as the fighting stormed all around them.
    >   Artoo and Threepio were huddled behind a log when Artoo got the message. He suddenly blurted out an excited whistle and shot off toward the battlefield.
- ***Why bother with camo, if you have C-3PO:***

  - The point of camo clothing isn't just to hide you - it's to break up your outline to make it harder to aim at you.
  - The team isn't always around C-3PO. Leia is away from the team with Wicket. During most of the post-godhood fighting, most of the team isn't with C-3PO - he and R2 are off hiding, near the bunker

    > Artoo and Threepio were huddled behind a log when Artoo got the message. He suddenly blurted out an excited whistle and shot off toward the battlefield.